Driver problem with 780M (Ryzen 7 7840HS iGPU)
I have HP Victus 16 with configuration Ryzen 7 7840HS(780M iGPU) and RTX3050. There is issues with my 780M iGPU. It gives black screen on Linux 6.9.1 when using iGPU. Using dGPU (which is RTX3050) from BIOS works perfectly. Furthermore, latest AMD drivers in Windows has same issues.
Ubuntu 24.04 has different problems. Sometimes it has black screen in internal monitor of my laptop. I could not find any solutions to it.

Do you have thew Nvidia graphics drivers installed?

Yes, latest Nvidia drivers installed. It probably happens because of HP. HP provided drivers run without issue in Windows but latest AMD drivers crash as well. But i could not find a solution in Linux side.

Update UEFI if available.

Unfortunately everyting up to date.
